# Required properties in .NET with a default constructor

Tags: c#

One of my classes require that a default constructor be used for serialization purposes. However, since some of the properties are required, what is the best way to approach this such that I can require that properties be set.

From where I am standing, I see two possible scenarios:

- I can use data annotations or something such that I put a [Required] attribute on the property, and before serialization check that each [Required] property has a value, or
- I can put validation logic elsewhere in the class to ensure that properties are properly set.

Comment: I think you mean deserialization.

Comment: Only serialize objects that meet this requirement and there's little to worry about at deserialization time.  Never serialize bad data.

Comment: @HansPassant That doesn't stop someone from futzing with the serialized data and "breaking" it. You should never trust data that you don't control.

Answer (score 3):

I would keep it simple and don't mess with attributes.

```
public interface IDataValidator
{
    void ValidateData();
}

public string Serialize<T>(T obj):where T:IDataValidator
{
    obj.ValidateData();
    return Serialize(obj);
}

public T Deserialize<T>(string serializedObj):where T:IDataValidator
{
    T obj = Deserialize(serializedObj);
    obj.ValidateData();
}

public class Book : IDataValidator
{
    public string Isbn {get;set;}

    public Book(){}
    public Book(string isbn)
    {
        Isbn = isbn;
    }

    public void ValidateData()
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace(Isbn)
            throw new ApplicationException("...");
    }
}
```